# Unable to get Additional Value from Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a dictionary collection which consist "TextDescription" and "TextValues" (List Collection) which has two objects "Date","Text"
"TextDescription":"Your payment due date is dec 12 on every month"
*0 th Item
"Date"=> "12/12/2018"
"Text"=>"A,B,C,D,E,F"

1 st Item
"Date"=> "12/12/2019"
"Text"=>"G,H,I,J,K,L"*

I have to split the "Text" object with it's comma separated values and add it in a list so I achieved it from below code

```
 var lstDictionaryItems = cache.Get(CacheKeys.AutoText) as Dictionary<string, Autotext>;
 var txtItemsList = lstDictionaryItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.ToString() == _languageIndicator.ToString()).Value.
 TextValues.SelectMany(st => st.Text.Split(',').Select(x => new TextValues { Date = x.Trim(), Text = st.Text }));
```

However I have achieved the Text and Date fields in a separate list item but I left with "TextDescription".

txtItemsList doesn't have the property "TextDescription" how can I get this in txtItemList object

Here is my class structure

```
public class AutoText
    {
        public string TextDescription{ get; set; }
        public List<TextValues> TextValues{ get; set; }
    }
    public class TextValues
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Text{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what is `Autotext` class, how it's look like?

Comment: Updated in the question section pls review

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add that code to your question instead of posting it as comment.

Comment: @SayeedAhmed `lstDictionaryItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.ToString() == _languageIndicator.ToString()).Value` contains what you want, what is the expected result, if you can just specify it based in the input data? and i have  remark `x.Trim()` is not a date, it's just `A`,`B` ....

Comment: @Sajid This line basically checks for specific key exist or not in Dictionary lstDictionaryItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.ToString() == _languageIndicator.ToString()).Value , In my case it has got two keys ("EA","EB") especially in _languageIndicator

Later I'm trying to fetch the values of AutoText class

The problem I'm facing now is I can able to access only the TextValues collection class but not TextDescription property  

x.Trim() consisting of Date property values and st.Text consisting of Text property values and I see those properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<string>> inputs = new List<List<string>>(){
                new List<string>(){"Your payment due date is dec 12 on every month","12/12/2018","A,B,C,D,E,F"},
                new List<string>(){"Your payment due date is dec 12 on every month","12/12/2019","G,H,I,J,K,L"}
            };

            var listInput = inputs.Select(x => new {TextDescription = x[0], Date = DateTime.Parse(x[1]), Text = x[2]}).ToList();

            Dictionary<DateTime, AutoText> dict = listInput.Select(x => new AutoText()
            {
                TextDescription = x.TextDescription,
                TextValues = x.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(y => new TextValues() { Date = x.Date, Text = y }).ToList()
            }).GroupBy(x => x.TextValues.FirstOrDefault().Date, y => y)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                
          
        }
    }
    public class AutoText
    {
        public string TextDescription { get; set; }
        public List<TextValues> TextValues { get; set; }
    }
    public class TextValues
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```